# How can I configure Angular to provide MyMonad<MyService> when injection of MyService dependency is requested in a constructor?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, eslint, typescript-eslint, ng-modules

I have `'@typescript-eslint/prefer-readonly-parameter-types': error` set in my eslintrc file for my Angular project. To make this rule more easily enforceable, I have a `DeepReadonly<T>` monadic type defined to wrap objects to make them readonly.

Now, if I want to inject MyService into MyComponent without violating the lint rule, I have to set up MyComponent's constructor like this:

`constructor(private readonly myService: DeepReadonly<MyService>)`

This isn't enough, though, as I get this error when I try to build: `No suitable injection token for parameter 'myService' of class 'MyComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.`

That seems to be a good suggestion, as now everything builds fine when I change the constructor to:

`constructor(@Inject(MyService) private readonly myService: DeepReadonly<MyService>)`

However, since I am injecting this service into multiple components, I'd rather not have to use the `@Inject` decorator every time. Is there a way to force the provider for this service (or, ideally, *any* service) to use `DeepReadonly<MyService>` whenever there is a request to have `MyService` injected, assuming it's not possible or unsafe to manually create a new instance of `MyService`?

I'd like to be able to do something like this in AppModule, but it doesn't work:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    MyComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: MyService, useClass: DeepReadonly<MyService> } // TS2693: 'DeepReadonly' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way dependency injection works, I think you'll likely have to either:

1. use `@Inject` every time; or
2. use something like `class DeepReadOnlyMyService extends MyService { ... }`; or
3. possibly find a way to re-work `MyService` such that the deeper properties are already `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the provider using a factory: useFactory

Comment: I tried that but I was still required to use `@Inject`, which I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Use **MyService** instead of using  **DeepReadonly** on the constructor.
You should get your **MyService** on your component's constructor directly like below:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService)
```

Comment: How would I ensure that `myService` is an instance of `DeepReadonly<MyService>`?